# Simplesamlphp wrong metadata

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml

I'm making two application with simplesaml, an Service Provider and an Identity Provider.

While I'm trying to test them out I get the following error:

```
SimpleSAML_Error_MetadataNotFound: METADATANOTFOUND('%ENTITYID%' => '\'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp\'')
Backtrace:
3 /var/www/samlidp/lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/MetaDataStorageHandler.php:301 (SimpleSAML_Metadata_MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetaData)
2 /var/www/samlidp/lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/MetaDataStorageHandler.php:318 (SimpleSAML_Metadata_MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetaDataConfig)
1 /var/www/samlidp/modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:303 (sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest)
0 /var/www/samlidp/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:18 (N/A)
```

This is the metadata of the sp:

```
$metadata['http://samlidp.dev/saml2/idp/metadata.php'] = array (
    'name' => 'test',
    'description' => 'next login test',
    'SingleSignOnService' => 'http://samlidp.dev/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
    'SingleLogoutService' => 'samlidp.dev/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
    'certFingerprint' => '38:EB:B2:DB:6F:45:C2:D6:92:CE:85:29:6B:CE:A6:D0:CE:91:19:7A'
);
```

And this is the metadata of the IdP:

```
$metadata['http://samlsp.dev'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService'=> 'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    'SingleLogoutService'=> 'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp'
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Apparently I made a call to the wrong metadata.

First it was this

```
$metadata['http://samlsp.dev'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService'=> 'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    'SingleLogoutService'=> 'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp'
);
```

but it had to be this:

```
$metadata['http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService'=> 'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    'SingleLogoutService'=> 'http://samlsp.dev/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp'
);
```

I made a call to the wrong metadata and my IdP couldn't find the metadata for it

Comment: Hello @Wouter i am looking for process how to implement SSO in laravel, I have metadata XML file (IDP) but what to do next with that detail and where to put that? i did not know much about this can you help on this?